# How do I handle the whitespaces of a registry path?

Tags: c#, string, registry, string-formatting, registrykey

I'm creating a process in my application that makes it possible to run commands like you do it in the command prompt.

When I want to export a registry key, I use `REG EXPORT path file` to access the registry key and export the information into the file. If I use a path which contains no whitespaces at all, everything works fine. But as soon as I use a path with whitespaces, e.g. `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\NVIDIA Corporation`, it does not work.

I'm appending the path as a String with a StringBuilder to the command, the String itself looks like this: `String path = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Software\\NVIDIA Corporation"`.

Do I have to change the String contained in `path`? Or is there a special static method I can use to format the String?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the code. Do you have to surround the path with quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to surround the path with quotes.
This might help:

```
String path = "\"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Software\\NVIDIA Corporation\"";
```

Comment: Yeah, that helped! Thanks!